# How to highlight the button when clicked in jquery using toggleclass?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've the following group of buttons and when those button or buttons is/are clicked in the group then the color of the clicked buttons must be high-lightened. How do I achieve this using toggle class or else please share me with any another approach if not toggleclass.

```
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
                                            <div class='input-group input-group-sm'>
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">Week</span></div>
                                            <button class="btn" name="WeekButtonGroup" id="week1_sat">
                                                S</button>
                                            <button class="btn" name="WeekButtonGroup" id="week1_sun">
                                                S</button>
                                            <button class="btn" name="WeekButtonGroup" id="week1_mon">
                                                M</button>
                                            <button class="btn" name="WeekButtonGroup" id="week1_tue">
                                                T</button>
                                            <button class="btn" name="WeekButtonGroup" id="week1_wen">
                                                W</button>
                                            <button class="btn" name="WeekButtonGroup" id="week1_thu">
                                                T</button>
                                            <button class="btn" name="WeekButtonGroup" id="week1_fri">
                                                F</button>
                                        </div>
    </div>




function highlightwhenclicked() {
 $('[name="WeekButtonGroup"]').each(function (index, element) {

            $(this).click(function () {
                   $(this).removeClass('active'); 


                    }
})
}
```

I know $(this).toggleClass can do this but how? I don't mind about what color but button must be high-lightened when clicked. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could just css `[name="WeekButtonGroup"]:active{new: style}`. No need for jQuery unless you're really planning on animating the hell out of it.http://jsbin.com/pilekuji/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/4uzRj/